# Laravel Elloquent Model Table Relations

Tags: laravel

I am learning Laravel and there is one thing I cannot solve.

**What do I have:**

Table of Users, Posts, Comments and corresponding Models

User.php:

`public function comments() { return $this->hasMany(Comment::class); }`

```
public function publishComment(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comments()->save($comment);
    }
```

Post.php:

`public function comments() { return $this->hasMany(Comment::class); }`

Comment.php:

```
public function post() { return $this->belongsTo(Post::class); } 

public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }
```

**What do I want?**

Since I have Blog, one logged user can create many posts (this works).
But same logged user can create many comments to one post. (User has many comments, post has many comments).

**Tables:**

User: | id | name | email | password

Comment: | id | user_id | post_id | body

Post: | id | user_id | title | body

**What have I tried?**
I created controller

CommentsController:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function store(Post $post)
{

    $this->validate(request(), ['body' => 'required|min:2']);

    auth()->user()->publishComment(

        new Comment(request('body'));

    );

    return back();

}
```

And in my blade file I simply want $comment->user->name  (get name of user who does the comment belongs to)

**Error I get**: 
*Trying to get property of non-object*

```
<?php echo e($comment->user->name); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well did you pass a $comment variable to your blade view?

Comment: @foreach($post->comments as $comment)   yes, sorry fot not mentioning this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) Relationship.

**Table Structure**

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text
    user_id - integer

users
    id - integer
    name - string
    email - string
    password - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

Into `commentable_id` you save the User `id` or the Post `id`.
Into `commentable_type` you save the `User` Model or `Post` Model.
And also you can have another table using comments table.

**Models**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the users's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

See the docs to get more details.

In this video you have a good explanation https://youtu.be/lePjXdMC6aM

Comment: Ok, this seems like exactly what I need. Can u explain why my solution doesn't work? is it because of trying to assign more relations to one model?

Comment: No, there is no the problem with relations quantity. I dont know but...
If the Omar Tarek answer is not the problem, I think that your problem is in the controller that returns the view with the post data.

Comment: Could you do a `{{ dd($comment) }}` inside `@foreach` loop and put the output here?

Comment: Comment {#202 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▶]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}

Comment: should i put it better formated inside question or is this OK?

Comment: now  try to do `{{ dd($comment->user) }}` in the same place

Comment: User {#208 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}

Comment: now try with `{{ $comment->user ? $comment->user->name : 'NOT USER'}}`

Comment: Can I use this knowledge to make my store method in CommentsController publish user related comments?

Comment: The problem is: some `Comment` doesn't have a `User`. See the "NOT USER" response into blade

Comment: oh, I see, but all my comments have their user_id, now I tried  {{ $comment->user->name}}     and it works! now back to my origin Q, how to make my CommentsController publis comment with user id? something like: auth()->user()->addComment(request(''body)); ??

Comment: in reality you dont need the `publishComment` method. You can do directly into a controller method.  See that https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: I get it, I can do this: https://ideone.com/ufndFD
but there is still no user_id which i need to attach to this comment

Comment: you must do `auth()->user()->comments()->save($comment);` ***OR*** `auth()->user()->comments()->create(request()->all());` the last way I think is the best beacuse you have all into a one line

Comment: yeah this is good, but now we lost relation to a post, I need both post_id and user_id (put together $post->comments()->save($comment); WITH auth()->user()->comments()->create($comment);

Comment: I think I got it! https://ideone.com/swikO3  this one works, can I do it like so?

Comment: I'm only helping you to understand why did not works your first code. i still thinking that you need to implement a Polymorphic Relations Relationship like I show you into my answer

Comment: Ok, will check it out, thanks for your patience and help! Have a great one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in your view.blade.php:

```
// Here I am assuming you have a $post variable that contains your blog post.
<ul>
    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
      <li>{{ $comment->user->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This will loop over all the comments that you have for your blog post and display the owner's name, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Then you don't have a $post variable maybe? Show us the code in your index method, the method you use to load the blade page initially.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this if you need just the name of the person who created comment.

```
{{ $post->user->name }}
```

Or

user->name); ?>

Comment: $post->user->name brings the name of user associated to a post. But what If different user comments on post? (like Pavel comments Adam's post)

Comment: you have comment table in relation to post table in your post model.
by adding {{ $post->user->name }} it will list all of the user who have commented the post. try it

Comment: I added to sql table  a comment with id of different user of who created the post and your solution gave me post creator name. I dont see the connection to comment's->user_id in this solution. There is just a connection to Post

Comment: Make a relation of comments to user table and then try to access each user against  comment table with tinker. this way you can find the best way to show all users who have commented particular post.
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

Comment: Make a relation of comments to user table and then try to access each user against  comment table with tinker. this way you can find the best way to show all users who have commented particular post.
in Comment model add this relation and then access users.
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }